# Selecting multiple relationships in Mysql Workbench

Tags: database, database-design, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to fix some `relationships` in my database modelling from `identifying` to `non-identifying`.

However, it seems that I have to select individual relationships and then make each of them non-identifying one by one.

Is there a way where I can select multiple relationships and then make them non-identifying by a single action?

I'm using `Mysql Workbench` for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no batch processing in MySQL Workbench. You have to edit one by one.